# {"msg":"Current request is not a multipart request","code":500}

Tags: html, forms

The form works with postman, but it doesn't work in server and local. The error is in the subject title.

```
<form class="form" action="POST">
            <div class="input-group">
                <label for="withdraw-address" class="form-label"> Withdraw Address </label>
                <input name="withdraw-address" type="text" class="form-control" id="withdraw-address">
            </div>
            <div class="input-group">
                <label for="receive-address" class="form-label"> Receive Address</label>
                <input name="receive-address" type="text" class="form-control" id="receive-address">
            </div>
            <div class="input-group">
                <label for="quanity" class="form-label"> Quanity </label>
                <input name="quanity" type="text" class="form-control" id="quanity">
            </div>
            <div class="input-group">
                <label for="remark" class="form-label">Remark</label>
                <input name="remark" type="text" class="form-control" id="remark">
            </div>
            <div class="input-group">
                <label for="withdraw-snapshot" class="form-label">Withdraw Snapshot</label>
                <input name="withdraw-snapshot" type="file" class="form-control" id="withdraw-snapshot" aria-describedby="inputGroupFileAddon04" aria-label="Upload">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn-form">Submit</button>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

change this line

```
<form class="form" action="POST">
```

to

```
<form class="form" action="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

then  issue is solved.

Answer (score 0):

If the form includes multipart data (multi-media data **eg. files**) make sure you change the **'enctype'** from **"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"** (default) to **"multipart/form-data"**.